# zxing reader in landscape mode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, zxing

I have a issue ; I have used zxing library for my iPad application; it works fine to read the qr code.

But its reader  in landscape mode rotates the live feed from the camera  to 90 degrees right; I want it to be without rotation just like in portrait mode where there is no rotation.

in portrait mode , the video feed is not rotated;have a look
[image: in portrait mode , the video feed is not rotated;have a look]

But in Landscapemodeleft , the video feed is rotated;have a look again
[image]

Comment: have you implemented shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation method by returning YES?

Comment: Yes, I have assigned YES to it , the reader launches in landscape but also rotates the live feed to 90 degrees right , that's the issue it should not rotate the live feed to 90 degrees i.e the feed shows everything vertical where as it should be horizontal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Zxing` library uses `AVFoundation` framework to show live camera layer. This layer(`prevLayer`) is added on the `ZXingWidgetController`'s view layer in `initCapture`  method. So whenever you rotate your camera this layer also rotate. To keep this layer in fixed position you will need to rotate it again by  `0, M_PI, -M_PI/2, M_PI/2` in `portrait, upsideDown, landscapeRight, landscapeLeft` using following rotation transform

```
CATransform3D transform =  CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1.0);
self.prevLayer.transform =transform;
self.prevLayer.frame = frame; // you may need to set it also if needed.
```

---

Comment: CATransform3D transform =  CATransform3DMakeRotation(190.7, 0, 0, 1.0);
self.prevLayer.transform =transform; works thanks !

Comment: Hey thanks, you'd rather use M_PI_2 instead of M_PI/2 to avoid imprecision. Anyway good anwer !